# how find count average using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a data like this

```
    +-------------+-------+
    | countryCode | label |
    +-------------+-------+
    | KM          | A     | 
    +-------------+-------+
    | AD          | A     | 
    +-------------+-------+
    | TH          | B     |
    +-------------+-------+
    | KM          | B     |
    +-------------+-------+
```

How can find average count like this

```
    +-------------+-----+-----+-------+
    | countryCode | A   | B   | count |
    +-------------+-----+-----+-------+
    | KM          | 0.5 | 0.5 | 2     |
    +-------------+-----+-----+-------+
    | AD          | 1   | 0   | 1     |
    +-------------+-----+-----+-------+
    | TH          | 0   | 1   | 1     |
    +-------------+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: what do *you* think? did you try anything?

Comment: I try many things subquery join still didn't get the result I want

Comment: I don't understand the arithmetic

Comment: @Strawberry What i mean I want to find the count average of A & B

Comment: For example KM have 2 count but have A & B so A has 50% of count and B has 50% of the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
SELECT countrycode
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'A' THEN 1 END)/COUNT(*),0) a 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY countrycode;
```

You can figure out the rest.

Comment: `
SELECT
 countrycode,
 COALESCE ( SUM( CASE WHEN label = 'A' THEN 1 END ) / COUNT( * ), 0 ) A,
 COALESCE ( SUM( CASE WHEN label = 'B' THEN 1 END ) / COUNT( * ), 0 ) B,
 COUNT(countryCode) as count
FROM my_table
`

Comment: Yes. It's called engaging brain. "Finally"? Seriously.

Comment: sorry if i offended you, I'm a total noob :). I also found other solution `SUM( IF ( label = 'A', 1, 0 ) ) / COUNT( * )`

Comment: I'm not offended. Just disappointed. Anyway, in MySQL, you can also simplify that to `SUM(label='A')`